# how to printing data with template module

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

My English is little bit poor so don't hesitate me if didn't understand.
I have problem with perl template tool kit module. This is my first experience using this module.I am reading xml data from file and I used XML::Simple(ForceArray) to parse and DATA::Dumper to print. Printing data is

```
$var1={

       'data'=>{
                  'employee'=>[
                            {
                           'name'=>'suraj',
                           'number'=>'f11a0478',
                           'adress'=>' badvel,kadapa,a.p,india',
                            },

                           {
                           'name'=>'misra',
                           'number'=>'047902',
                           'adress'=>' raipur,ananthapur,a.p,india',
                            }...........
                             ...........
                          ],          

    'company'=>{
              'name'=>'bosch',
              'location'=>'banglore',
              'domain'=>{
                     'java'=>{
                            'employee'=>[
                                     {
                                    'name'=>'suraj',

                                    'number'=>'f11a0478',

                                    'experience'=>{
                                              'years'=>'3',
                                              'projects'=>'4',

                                              }
                                           },
                                   {
                                    'name'=>'misra',

                                    'number'=>'047902',

                                    'experience'=>[
                                                 {
                                                  'years'=>'1',

                                                  'projects'=>'1',

                                                  },
                                                 {
                                             'years'=>'1',

                                             'projects'=>'1',

                                              }
                                             ]
                                           },   
                                          ]
                            }
                    }................
                    .................
             };
```

I used template toolkit process like this and printed in some file, I written code like this

```
[% FOREACH comp IN company %]
[% comp.name %] 
[% comp.location%]
employeedata:
[% FOREACH employee IN comp.domain.java.employee %]
employee name: [% employee.name +%] numb [%+ employee.number %]
   [% FOREACH experience IN employee. experience %]
[% experience.years %]
[% experience.projects %]
 [% END %]
 [% END %]
[% END %]
```

From above script I am able to print company employee, name, number, experience, years ,projects. But my problem is I need to add address of employee also to this information. I am printing all information in company node and for all company's. But Address is located some other key in the hash. By using employee name and number(some employee having same name some having same number) I need to find the address and print the address in the employee details. help me with this problem. What should I do now, how to solve this problem.

Comment: "By using employee name and number(some employee having same name some having same number)" You mean name is a unique identifier as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
[% FOREACH de IN data.employee %]
  [% IF de.name == employee.name && de.number == employee.number %]
    [% de.address %]
    [% LAST %]
  [% END %]
[% END %]
```

I'd recommend doing something about the data structure before processing it with TT though, because this isn't very efficient. If comp.domain.java.employee and data.employee contains the same number of elements it's pretty straight forward.

**EDIT:** What I meant in my comment below is

```
[% FOREACH employee IN comp.domain.java.employee %]
  [% addresses = [] %]
  [% FOREACH de IN data.employee %]
    <!-- Name, experience etc. -->
    <!-- Then new address stuff: -->
    [% IF de.name == employee.name || de.number == employee.number %]
      [% addresses.push(de.address) %]
    [% END %]
  [% END %]
  [% addressStr = addresses.join(', '); addressStr.replace(', ([^,]+)$', ' or $1') %]
  [% addressStr %]
[% END %]
```

That's not printing addresses like `address1, address2 or address3`?

Comment: Thank you very much , Its working good for me and also output also looking good. but you said do something before processing means i need to change data structure.

Comment: It's only a recommendation, since it would make sense to have the current addresses in the same hash as your other data for presentation. It might not be that big of a deal if your dataset isn't too large though.

Comment: yeah exactly your right, my data is very simple and above process is working good thank you very much for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: ,Sorry for asking question here,in the problem I posted I have two employee names under employee so it executes two times and printing two emplyee's address but the problem is it printing two employee address combindly so I placed coma like this in your code          [% de.address %], after this it printing like this     address1,address2, if I have three names under employee tag it prints like this  address1,address2,address3, but how can I print like this address1,address2. and if three names is there like this address1,address2 or address3. can you please tel me how to do this.

Comment: This is untested, but maybe something like `[% addresses = [] %][% FOREACH de IN data.employee %]
  [% IF de.name == employee.name && de.number == employee.number %]
    [% addresses.push(de.address) %]
  [% END %]
[% END %][% addressStr = addresses.join(', '); addressStr.replace(',([^,]+)$', ' and $1') %][% addressStr %]`

Comment: I tried as you said but it printing one address two times and also if I have two address it printing second one two times it doesn't print first address. same thing when I have three address it printing last address two times. first and second both skipped.I can't understand why because I am very new to this.can you help me please.